# How to translate angular variables, without modify DOM?

Tags: angularjs, translation

I have a big angular app.
How to translate variables, without change DOM elmenets?

Eg:

```
<div data-ng-bind="{{ hello }}"></div>
```

I dont want to edit this HTML, but I would like to hello variable.
No filter, no any change. 
Changes made by only js side.

Comment: You need to provide a bit more detail as to what it is you are trying to do. Also what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a *decorator* to compile state.

Use the $provide.decorator function to change normal interpolation method.

```
$provide.decorator( "$interpolate", ... );
```

More information:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#decorator

Answer (score 1):

If you mean adding localization and multi-language support, there are plenty of libraries to help you out. Take a look at [ng-i18next](https://github.com/i18next/ng-i18next).

Comment: Thanks your advance.
Unfortunately not right this module, because need add filters later to DOM elements.